# Lightswitch Choice List changer based other column condition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have a table called Members on my Lightswitch application.
[image: My Member Table and it's Columns]

I want to add a choice list for MemberType (String) that be related to my isAEDSMember (boolean) column.

```
isAEDSMember (Boolean)
if(isAEDSMember == true){
myChoiceList {1,2,3,4}
}else{
myChoiceList {3,4}
}
```

I think it's possible only with c# code. currently i don't have any idea about the method and syntax of making this option.

Comment: Just to check, are you using the Silverlight or HTML client in your project?

Comment: I'm using Silverlight desktop client